# I need help in java

Tags: java

so in the code I'm working itread from the input file and writes that info to the output file. in the input file I have this info 1245: my address: miami, fl

then when the information is being written down in the output I need it to change the : for |. can anyone explain how can I do This.

```
import java.io.*;


public class fileConverted {

public static void main(String args[]) {        
    try {
        File input = new File("input");
        File output = new File("output");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);   
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            printer.write(s);
        }
        printer.flush();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
    }
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Before writing to output file invoke String.replaceAll() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
char x=f.read();
if(x==':')
x='|';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line :

```
s = s.replace(":", "|");
```

After

```
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it is working perfectly

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class fileConverted 
{
     public static void main(String args[]) 
     {        
         try 
         {
             File input = new File("input.txt");
             File output = new File("output.txt");
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);   
             PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
             while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
             {
                    String s = sc.nextLine();
                    printer.write(s.replace(':', '|'));
                 }
             printer.flush();
          }
          catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
      {
            System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
          }
    }
}
```